# Button is self-pushing (JS)

Tags: javascript, button

Logout button class, Im creating instance to connect it with API. After the moment instance created it is immediately activated like the button was pushed
Can you help to understand what is wrong?
I'm just beginner

```js
class LogoutButton {
    constructor() {
        [this.logoutBtn] = document.getElementsByClassName('logout');
        this.action = (f) => f;
        this.logoutBtn.addEventListener('click', this.logoutClick.bind(this));
    }

    logoutClick(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        this.action();
    }
}
```

instance

```js
"use strict"

let newLogoutButton = new LogoutButton();

const logoutSuccess = (data) => {
    if (data.success === true) {
        location.reload();
    } else {
        alert("");
    }
};

newLogoutButton.action = ApiConnector.logout(logoutSuccess);
```

Comment: It really depends on exactly what `ApiConnector.logout` does, and since you haven't given any code for that it's difficult to tell.  But it seems like it's actually invoking the logout operation by calling `logoutSuccess`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue is with the last line
`newLogoutButton.action = ApiConnector.logout(logoutSuccess);`

change it to
`newLogoutButton.action = () => ApiConnector.logout(logoutSuccess);`

Answer (score 0):

The last line needs to be a function, right now you're just immediately calling `.logout()`

```js
newLogoutButton.action = () => ApiConnector.logout(logoutSuccess);
```